# Set a canvas to be fixed to the window width and resize without javascript?

Tags: css, html, canvas, css-position

I am creating an image viewer with a canvas which will pop open in a new window.  I would like the canvas to be the width of the window and 100px from the top and bottom.  I would also like for it to resize without using javascript (let me handle the redrawing in javascript - I just want to see the canvas stay fixed to the edges of the window with the top and bottom spacing.)  How can I do this?  I tried the following but the right and bottom are ignored:

```
.contextCanvas
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
}
```

Any suggestions or reasoning as to why the browser will happily ignore the right and bottom?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer - I had to wrap the canvas in a container div which was fixed positioned and then set the inner canvas to absolute positioning and 100% width & height.

HTML

```
<div class="canvasContainer">
    <canvas class="contextCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS

```
.canvasContainer
{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: Black;
}

.contextCanvas
{   position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```